# How do I avoid memory issue when sending large content returned from Hibernate on the fly?

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, download, heap-memory

I have a list of object in the memory(getting it from the database). I am converting it to CSV format and zip it to send it to the client on the fly. Since I am assigning the large records returned by Hibernate to a List, I am afraid that  getBookList method causes Java heap memory issue. Following is my Servlet and Hibernate code.

```
final String[] header = new String[] { "Author", "BookName", "ISNB"}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
            "booklist.zip");
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);     
    final ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out),
                8192);
    ICsvBeanWriter csvBeanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(writer,
            CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
    csvBeanWriter.writeHeader(header);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("books.csv");
    out.putNextEntry(entry);
    List<Book> bookList = bookDAO.getListofBooks(booIdList);//getting if from the database using hibernate
    for (Book book : bookList) {
        csvBeanWriter.write(book, header);
    }
    writer.flush();
    csvBeanWriter.close();
    out.closeEntry();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

Following is Hibernate DAO implementatin class.

```
public List<Book> getBookList(List<Interger> isbnList) {
    DetachedCriteria criteriaObj = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Book>.class);
    criteriaObj.add(Restrictions.in("id", (isbnList)));
    criteriaObj.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<PackageDataCSV> result = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteriaObj);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what's "big"? what kind of memory limits are set on your environment?

Comment: are you getting a "out of java heap space" error?

Comment: @Marc. If write the list to the file, it is around 480K before zip. So, this is considered big now. I actually need to handle much more than that. I am just wondering if there is any logic errors in my code.

Comment: @developerwjk I don't get java heap error since JVM should able handle 480K easily.

Comment: @Marc and developerwjk: It turns out that this code works fine. I had problem with my client side. Now, main problem is that the Hibernate code return all records from database and assign it to the array. When the records is large, I might get memory issue. How do I avoid that? I might new to open new question.